# Surround SCM integration with Eclipse for Android project

Tags: android, surroundscm

I have a bunch of code in Surround SCM, which I would like to get into a workspace in Eclipse. I will need to be able to work off of two branches. One for bug fixes, and one for new features, which can then be merged into my main branch. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I work for Seapine but I wasn't involved with anything to do with Eclipse.

What we do here internally is have a separate Java project for each branch in a single Eclipse workspace. To do so create a workspace somewhere and do:

File->New Project...->Java Project

This brings up the new project dialog. You can then point the project at the existing source path for the first branch, in my case the mainline branch, using the "Create project existing source" radio. I think I might have an older version of Eclipse installed but it should be the same or similar in new ones.

Clicking Next will take you to the next screen.

[image]

Here you can set up specific settings for this branch, like packages to exclude or things like that.

[image]

Click Finish and your project will be set up. Just repeat the same steps for a different branch using a different disk location.

Once you make changes to your branch code you can just check it into Surround SCM, promote it to the mainline, then do a get bring down the changes locally to your other directory.

Comment: This doesn't work for Android projects. There must be some extra step, or other path to follow for Android.